# How can I add exceptions for sorting Django models?

Tags: django, django-models

I've got a line in python:

```
streams = Stream.objects.filter(info__isnull = False)\
        .order_by('-score', 'info__title')
```

I feed that to a RequestContext

```
c = RequestContext(request, {
    'online_streams': streams.filter(online = True),
    'offline_streams': streams.filter(online = False)
})
```

It sorts a table of ~50 rows by their score and title. This is good, but there is one row I would like to **always** be top. Simply fetching it beforehand and filtering it out of the line above, then give it to the RequestContext separately won't work, since I'd have to modify the template. Also I might change which row should be on top later, or perhaps make it multiple rows instead.

Is there a filter argument I can insert that says something in the lines of *"Order all rows by score then title, except row ID 8, which should always be top"*? Or could I perhaps change the order of the QuerySet manually after the filtering?

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: What's wrong with modifying the template? You try to make some hack, why not to make it properly? So anyone who will look at your code (including you) will understand what's going on and why.

Comment: Of course I can't change the template in my case. It's job is to display the rows it's handed. Having one or more rows stuck to the top is a fleeting thing, it won't always be that way. It's silly to be editing the template every time I make a change.

Comment: It's silly to edit the template, bit it's not silly to edit view/model/manager? Ok. It's much easier, quicker and clearer to edit both view and template. But if you have a lot of time to invent strange hacks, why not. :-)

Comment: It's silly to edit the template, but it's not silly to customize the way the streams are sorted. That's the way I look at it :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to use query sets to do this, so I ended up converting the query set to a list and sorting it using the magic compare function. It ended up looking something like this:

The magic sorter, checking for names that should be stuck "on top":

```
# Comparison magic
def __cmp__(self, other):
    # On top
    if self.name in stream_ontop:
        return 1
    if other.name in stream_ontop:
        return -1

    # Score
    if self.score > other.score:
        return 1
    if self.score < other.score:
        return -1

    # Title alphabetical
    if self.info.title > other.info.title:
        return -1
    if self.info.title < other.info.title:
        return 1

    return 0
```

Then I fetched and sorted them like this from my model class

```
# Custom sorting
@staticmethod
def getAllSorted(online):
    streams = list(Stream.objects.filter(online=online, info__isnull=False))
    streams.sort(key=None, reverse=True)

    return streams
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override Model manager method:

class MyManager(models.Manager):

```
def filter(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return super(MyManager, self).filter(*args, **kwargs).exclude(id=8).order_by(...)
```

then in model

```
class Stream(models.Model):
    ...
    objects = MyManager()
```

EDIT
to make sure it is included you can query:

```
from django.db.models import Q
return super(MyManager, self).filter(Q(id=8) | Q(*args, **kwargs)).order_by(...)
```

Comment: I am not sure if it will work your way. I just wanted to show you, that orginal filter can be changed

Comment: From what I see of your code, you're just excluding id 8. How do you make sure it's included and on top?